# MuteSetup command doesn't setup a working Mute command

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I have recently been trying to make a Mute-Setup command, it creates a mute role but when you mute someone they can still talk. Any help?

My code:

```
if (raw.replace("S!", "").equals("mutesetup")) {
if (event.getMember().hasPermission(Permission.MANAGE_PERMISSIONS, Permission.MANAGE_ROLES)) {
if (true) {
event.getChannel().sendMessage("Sorry but this command is currently being fixed...").queue();
return;
}
event.getChannel().sendMessage("Starting setup...").queue();
event.getGuild().createRole().setName("Muted").setPermissions(Permission.EMPTY_PERMISSIONS).queue();
    
event.getChannel().sendMessage("Mute role successfully created!").queue();
} else {
event.getChannel().sendMessage("Sorry but you must have the `Manage Permissions` and `Manage Roles` permissions to use this command").queue();
}
}
```

Comment: The discord API docs describe that the permission is granted if another role (also the `@everyone`) has it. You need to configure channel overrides for this.

Answer (score 0):

By creating a role with `EMPTY_PERMISSIONS` sets all the role's permissions as DEFAULT meaning it will use the permission level of other roles (following the role hierarchy) the user has for said permission or of the `@everyone` role if non-applicable for other roles and then only if the everyone role has it disabled, so will they.

To make the muted role unable to send messages/talk you'll need to set the message sending permission/talk permission to deny in the channels/categories you wish them to be unable to talk like so:

```
category.createPermissionOverride(role).setDeny(Permission.MESSAGE_WRITE, Permission.VOICE_SPEAK).queue();
```

Answer (score 0):

*First of all, try possibly to format your code the next time so that it is clear.*

But to get back to your question, you must of course also adjust the permissions of your newly created role (since the name is irrelevant in terms of rights). In principle, you only have to deny the **Speak** permissions so that Discord also understands what users have in your newly created role, whether they are allowed to speak or not or whether they can write messages and so on.

You only have to add the following to your code after you have created the role, so that you can tell Discord what users can or cannot do with your role (As said above)

**If you add the following code, users with your role can NO longer speak and NO messages send more:**

```
category.createPermissionOverride(role).setDeny(Permission.VOICE_SPEAK, Permission.MESSAGE_WRITE).queue();
```

Of course, you can do the same with all other permissions. The opposite of **Deny (NO)** would be **Grant (Yes)**. It is best to read this section through to better understand Discord's permission system: [How do I set up Permissions?](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/206029707-How-do-I-set-up-Permissions-)